# To use raspbarry pi as iot device that can be controlled by python code on windows to turn on and off lights

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot, hardware, windows-10-iot-core

I am making a project on desktop virtual assistant with python. I want to add a feature that will turn on and off light by raspbarry pi.
And i am new to raspbarry pi so i want to ask that is it possible to excess rapbarry pi for light on or off with code written on windows not on raspbarry via internet.
And there is not much content on internet about related issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.If you don't write code on raspberry pi, how will the device receive the command to control light on/off? At the moment, there is no onboard service to do that. You can create UWP app on Windows IoT Core, and send the light on/off command via socket. Or you can build a web server with [.net core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/august/net-core-cross-platform-iot-programming-with-net-core-3-0) which supports IoT, and then call the web api with python on Windows Desktop.